# What to use for organising all my documents?

Tags: knowledge-organization

I think I want to go paperless, or at least have a copy of all my paper stuff on my PC. Now I'm quite open to any way possible, but I'm not sure how to do this, or which software to use. I have thought about 3 different ways, but none seem great:

- Using **Google Drive** and putting everything into folders. This has the advantage, that I don't need any other software. Also, thanks to Syncing I would have it on my phone and PC, and could easily add new documents from Notebloc. But that's about it, and I would have to rely on grouping together similar documents in folders, and names to find things. Not horrible, but maybe I can do better?
- **OneNote**. I already use it for some things, but it has really weird drawbacks. Not to mention the sync issues, aka taking really long to sync a small change. I assume I would create one page per receipt or dokument/Group of related documents? To be honest, it doesn't feel like it was designed for this, but I guess it works for me. But it does have some more drawbacks:

  First off, the mobile version sucks. I can't move pages around in a book, or manage sections. I tried importing my documents by making a document section in my book, and then having a Page for Receipts, and all receipts are subpages of this. And after that is a Page for my first Documents. Turns out, on the Android version, I have to scroll all the way past ALL my receipts, because it doesn't seem to be collapsable. It seems like a workaround would be to create a dedicated notebook for my documents, then a section for the receipts. But because collapsing already exists on desktop, it doesn't seem to me like something I should have to do.

  And, what might be an even bigger issue: OCR doesn't work. To make it work, I have to launch the old version of OneNote, even though I currently use the UWP one, and set the image as searchable there. Why??
- **Evernote**. I have tried it once as a replacement for Google Keep, Wunderlist, and notetaking in OneNote. It didn't work out for any of this, at least not for me. But maybe this is the purpose I can use it for?

Anyways, if you have a good alternative for OneNote, or know how to fix my issues with it, please tell me!

Comment: Have you already checked similar questions tagged [knowledge-organization](/questions/tagged/knowledge-organization) or [document-management](/questions/tagged/document-management)? There have been several questions with answers matching your needs already. Check e.g. [this list](/search?q=[document-management]+answers%3A1); right the first one matches organization incl. scan & OCR: [Simple open source document scan/tag/catalog more lightweight than Alfresco](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/21328/185)

Comment: Suppose you want to scan, make sure to avoid certain modes with TIFF. The problem is that it reuses patterns found elsewhere in the document, but isn't very precise. This has been found to cause peculiar issues with - mainly - numbers being switched out for other values. So there's more to this than picking a software.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works for me and is free.

I use an app called Notebloc to scan documents and then share them to OneNote. Drawbacks are that I can only do 10 pictures at a time, but that's alright. The scans look really good. In OneNote, I have a Notebook called Papers and then a section for Dokuments, one for Receipts, and one for Other things. The OCR needs a while to work (about 20 minutes after pasting), and while I still think it should be locally doable, after the time has passed searching works surpsigingly well.